# Error when flipping UIPageController programmatically in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have been trying to use `pageContainer.setViewControllers([displayThisViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)`to turn from viewControllerA to viewControllerB. This is my implementation of it in viewControllerA:

```
pageViewController().setViewControllers([viewControllerB()], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The problem that I have run into is that whenever I try to run this line of code I receive the error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What am I doing wrong? Is it something in my pageViewController class? Thanks in advance.

edit: both view controllers were created in the storyboard, and embedded into the UIPageViewController

edit: I understand what the error message means but I do not understand what is causing it or how to fix it.

Comment: What is viewControllerB( ) ? Is that the name of a class that you are constructing? Is it defined in a storyboard, because if so, this method of construction will not wire up any outlets.

Comment: @MikeTaverne It is a view controller created that was created in the storyboard and embedded into the UIPage controller